# Как дать название колонке?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть примерно такой SQL запрос:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT col1, col2, (col1 - col2) FROM mytable)
```

Как мне теперь вытащить только нужный (последний) столбец? Ведь в таблице он называется ?colunm?

```
SELECT ? FROM t
```

Comment: `... (col1 - col2) AS col3 ...`

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH t AS (SELECT col1, col2, (col1 - col2) as subresult FROM mytable)
```

И обращайся по названию subresult